# Fiction Advice: Country's Children

Tags: creative-writing, fiction, planning, world-building, child-characters

I had an idea for a setting.  I don't know if it has been done before.  What I thought of is that a government would collect children.  I am not sure if I should have the children be distributed to other families or if they are to be raised by government workers.  Maybe the children are raised by people, assigned by the government, and raised to do the job that their 'parents' do.

Is there any information that I can use for this?  Is there anything I should think about?

Comment: "I don't know if it has been done before." No matter what the idea is, the answer is probably 'yes'. But that doesn't have to be a problem!

Comment: The "Why" is *probably* very important to consider.  Are children "community raised" to prevent families / dynasties?  Are they [redistributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_Children) to areas of lower population?  Or are they just [not liked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Child_Catcher) by Government officials?

Comment: Check out _The Giver_ by Lois Lowry. In this utopian world, children are born by "birth-mothers" and distributed by the governing officials to whoever they please to give them to. (If I remember correctly.) Also, they are chosen for an occupation when they are a certain age, I believe. So similar idea, but not quite the same as what you're saying. As DM _with_ secrets says, you can still write from the idea even if it's been done before. Just don't completely copy someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Your short description makes me think of ways real world governments, that tried (and still try) to force people to assimilate into different cultures.

You should look into some sources detailing those events.
This might be a good start: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Indian_boarding_schools

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you could instead have it more like this: they should be raised, not necessarily by government workers but by people who the government chooses, and raised to do jobs that they were tested for? They could be raised off basic teachings that everyone receives, and when they reach a certain age (or year, such as December 12th of their 13 year or something), and then get tested to see what job fits them best. Then they get trained for that job from the point on.

Or you could have them raised by government workers, and redistributed to a job that the government chooses for them.

You should think of multiple ideas first, to be honest. Once you have them, lay them out, and then combine elements you like into one form while getting rid of elements you don't like. I've done it before with some of my stories. I'll take a couple of stories that I wrote, then combine them together with the elements that I like and take out the elements I don't like. I'll usually do it to stories that I no longer want to write, but I still want the story, or aspects of the story.